# How to use addLayoutComponent method of FlowLayout in applet?

Tags: java, applet, flowlayout

> Syntax: `void addLayoutComponent(String name,Component comp)`
>   desc: Adds the specified component to the layout.

NOTE: I can extend `Applet` (`java.applet.Applet`) only not `Frame` or `Window` or `Panel`.

Comment: Don't use Applets. They are deprecated. Use Swing or JavaFX.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Applets are in my university syllabus that's why i am using it.

Comment: [This is a very interesting](https://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) to read then. :)

Comment: @GeorgeZ. I appreciate that but i have to learn applet to pass exam.

Comment: As the author of the article @GeorgeZ. linked to, I can only feel sorry for you. But hey, this really comes down to a problem with layouts using AWT components. First of all, it's not recommended to add components directly to an applet, but instead a 'parent' container (`Panel`) and the short answer to your question is - don't. Don't use that method. Even more so than "don't use applets" which you are required to use. Just create a panel (the default layout is `FlowLayout`) add the component to it, then add the `Panel` to the `Applet`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank u sir, I appreciate your taking the time to answer my question.